# OpenGL Draw Text Alongside Objects

Tags: opengl, text, draw

I have this render function that is working:

```
    void RenderFunction(void)
{
    ++FrameCount;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    drawGraph();
    drawAxis(); 

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Which is rendering me a point graph. I want to be able to display a small text. I read this artice: http://www.codersource.net/MFC/OpenGL/DisplayingTextOpenGLTutorial5.aspx, and the only thing needed to do is copy that function and update my code:

```
void RenderFunction(void)
{
    ++FrameCount;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    drawBitmapText("Osama Hosam's OpenGL Tutorials",200,200,0);

    drawGraph();
    drawAxis(); 

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The renderFunction is called inside `glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);`

Any idea on this. I would like any suggestions because it is not showing anything.

UPDATE:

```
void drawGraph(){
    glBindVertexArray(VaoId);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glLineWidth(0);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 48, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)0);
    glPointSize(10);
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 48, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)0);
}

void drawAxis(){
    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glBindVertexArray(VaoIdAxis);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)0);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question Solved. For some reason, drawBitmapText() is not support in some OpenGL contexts. Initially i had:

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Which preventing the application from rendering the text. I just commented out that 3 lines and everything went great.